# Adding library source to eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

Right now I am using Maven Jars with my project. But I need to modify the source code of one the libraries I am using. I need to add the full source code of a library to my project. I tried adding it in different ways, but I get a lot of errors and eclipse is not treating it as part of the project.

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you add it to the .classpath file?

Answer (score 0):

First, find the actual project source, from the code repository which hosts it. Then clone/checkout the repository (with Eclipse or whatever) and import your library with `File > Open Projects from Filesystem...` or `File > Import > Existing Maven projects...` . Then library will be imported as project and Eclipse should relate it with your project.